# Why is GetManifestResourceStream returning null if used inside an async Method?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, .net-assembly

In my program I am writing a Resource File into some Location the user selects. For that I am using GetManifestResourceStream. Everything worked fine.

Next I wanted to make my writing operation not-blocking the UI. So I changed the code using async await. 
Unfortunately GetManifestRresourceStream is returning null now. Changing back without using async await everything works fine again.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it so that I am able to copy the file and the UI is not blocked.

This Is how it works without async/await (Please dont be confused by the Method Names)

```
 private void InstallButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InstallProgrammAsyc();
        }

private void InstallProgrammAsyc()
        {
            try
            {
                FinalMessage = "";
                PreInstallationBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                DuringInstallationBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                CopyFileToDestinationAsync("MyNameSpace", InstallPath, "Resources", "some.exe");
                PrepareProgrammForFinish();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DuringInstallationBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                AfterInstallationBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                FinalMessage = $"Unexpected Error occured. Please try again. {ex.Message}";
            }
        }

 private void CopyFileToDestinationAsync(string nameSpace,string outDirectory, string internalPath, string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(nameSpace + "." + (internalPath == "" ? "" : internalPath + ".") + resourceName))
            {
                using( BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
                {
                    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(outDirectory + "\\" + resourceName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                        {
                            // await Task.Run( ()=> bw.Write(br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length)));
                            bw.Write(br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            //For User Friendliness wait 2 seconds to finish
           // await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
        }


----------
```

And this Is how I tried it with async/await

```
        private async Task CopyFileToDestinationAsync(string nameSpace,string outDirectory, string internalPath, string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(nameSpace + "." + (internalPath == "" ? "" : internalPath + ".") + resourceName))
            {
                using( BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
                {
                    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(outDirectory + "\\" + resourceName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                        {
                             await Task.Run( ()=> bw.Write(br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length)));
                          //  bw.Write(br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Thread.Sleep(2000);
            //For User Friendliness wait 2 seconds to finish
            await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
        }


        private void FinishButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private async void InstallProgrammAsyc()
        {
            try
            {
                FinalMessage = "";
                PreInstallationBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                DuringInstallationBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                await CopyFileToDestinationAsync("MyNameSpace", InstallPath, "Resources", "some.exe");
                PrepareProgrammForFinish();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DuringInstallationBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                AfterInstallationBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                FinalMessage = $"Unexpected Error occured. Please try again. {ex.Message}";
            }
        }

        private void InstallButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InstallProgrammAsyc();
        }
```

Comment: I solved the problem by calling the GetManifestResourceStream Function outside and passing the Stream as a Parameter to the async Function. However I would really like to know why it is not functioning the way I tried before.

Comment: It's very likely that `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly` is not returning the assembly you're expecting

Comment: Yes maybe. I also tried to use the other ones. But that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting edge case, due to how async works.

Let's take those test methods:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowAssembly();
    ShowAssemblyAsync();
}

private void ShowAssembly()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

    MessageBox.Show(assembly.FullName);
}

private async void ShowAssemblyAsync()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

    MessageBox.Show(assembly.FullName);
}
```

In `ShowAssembly`, it'll display the name of your program's main assembly. In `ShowAssemblyAsync`, it'll display "mscorlib". What's going on?

If you put a breakpoint in `ShowAssembly` and `ShowAssemblyAsync` in Visual Studio, you'll get the following callstacks:

```
DesktopClient.exe!DesktopClient.MainWindow.ShowAssembly() Line 119  C#
DesktopClient.exe!DesktopClient.MainWindow.Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 109   C#
```

```
DesktopClient.exe!DesktopClient.MainWindow.ShowAssemblyAsync() Line 128 C#
DesktopClient.exe!DesktopClient.MainWindow.Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 110   C#
```

Nothing fishy there. However, Visual Studio is lying to you. If I instead use a lower level debugger (in this case, WinDbg), I get the following callstacks:

```
00efe58c 07cf423b DesktopClient.MainWindow.ShowAssembly() 
00efe5a8 07cf41dc DesktopClient.MainWindow.Button_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
```

```
00efe4d8 07cf43c6 DesktopClient.MainWindow+d__10.MoveNext() 
00efe51c 5ddaa48d System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.__Canon ByRef)
00efe574 07cf4317 DesktopClient.MainWindow.ShowAssemblyAsync()
00efe5a8 07cf41e6 DesktopClient.MainWindow.ButtonPlus_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
```

You can see that the callstack from `ShowAssemblyAsync` has been completely changed after applying the async keyword (Visual Studio is hiding that to make debugging easier). One consequence is that the method is now called by `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start`, and that's why we get "mscorlib" when retrieving the calling assembly.

As a fix, you can either use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` (assuming your `CopyFileToDestinationAsync` method is located in the right assembly) or target the assembly explicitly: `typeof(MainWindow).Assembly`. Or, like you did, just retrieve the stream before calling the method.

Yet another way is to introduce an extra non-async method just to retrieve the assembly before calling the real async implementation:

```
private Task CopyFileToDestinationAsync(string nameSpace,string outDirectory, string internalPath, string resourceName)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

    return CopyFileToDestinationAsync(assembly, nameSpace, outDirectory, internalPath, resourceName);
}

private async Task CopyFileToDestinationAsync(Assembly assembly string nameSpace,string outDirectory, string internalPath, string resourceName)
{
    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(nameSpace + "." + (internalPath == "" ? "" : internalPath + ".") + resourceName))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was really helpful for better understanding.